# How can I get all the days of the current week in android?

Tags: android

I want to get all the days in the current week in an array of Strings. How can I acheive this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're after. What would the contents of those strings be, exactly? If you could give an example, it would really help.

Comment: I want to get all the days of the current week like today is 09/16/2011, So I want to get all the days of this week...
ex-
Str[0]= 09/12/2011
Str[1]= 09/13/2011
Str[2]= 09/14/2011
Str[3]= 09/15/2011
Str[4]= 09/16/2011
Str[5]= 09/17/2011
Str[6]= 09/18/2011

Comment: Right - and *always* in that format, or in the user's default date format? (For example, 09/12/2011 looks like the 9th of December to me, as I'm in the UK.)

Comment: It should be in mm/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: What do you mean? You need to *specify* the format, or we can't answer you...

Comment: It should be in mm/dd/yyyy format.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I *think* you want something like this... assuming you always want weeks starting on Monday, and a date format of "MM/dd/yyyy".

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);

String[] days = new String[7];
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    days[i] = format.format(calendar.getTime());
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}
```

While I *think* that's correct, I personally use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) wherever possible - I'm aware that's slightly trickier on Android where you're more likely to have space concerns.

Comment: Hello, this is work for me but i am getting issue in some Samsung and some Moto devices, before   calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY); it will return correct date but when i set    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);  and get current  week with your code it will give me previous Week. Can you help me..

Comment: @UmeshAHIR: Not from just that description, I'm afraid. Please ask a new question with more details, ideally a [mcve].

Comment: Hello Jon Skeet i have create question, can you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49939067/getting-issues-on-get-current-week-days-on-some-device

Comment: after 8 years +1, Thank you

Comment: Works fine for me as well! Nice answer bro :p

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
        formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
```