# how to display current week days

Tags: android

help me i use this sample example http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/10/custom-calendar-in-android.html?showComment=1374298656772#c7739428050175524218    I want to print only current week of days. i want to display only single row. i modify this example  code to  my code. I replaced example code with this condition:  `if (i == currentWeekDay)`. But it only display first week of dates.  Today's date is 20 july.  Is does not show today date of week. My screen looks like this:

[image]

how i display current week only??

```
// Current Month Days
for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
 Log.d(currentMonthName, String.valueOf(i) + " "
  + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + " " + yy);
 if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth()) {
 list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-"
   + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
 } else {
 list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-"
   + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
 }
}

                    // Current Month Days
    for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
        Log.d(currentMonthName, String.valueOf(i) + " "
                + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + " " +  
        yy);
        if (i == currentWeekDay)
        {

        if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth()) {
            list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-"
                    + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) 
    +    "-" + yy);
        } else {
            list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-"
                    + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + 
      "-" + yy);
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: comp;lete code is here   http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/10/custom-calendar-in-android.html?showComment=1374233553950#c4705674682877024214

Comment: Hi Are you there I got the solution

Comment: I need a up vote and mark it correct..

Answer (score 0):

please try  https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid

U can also customize the custom calender according to your requirement.

Comment: ok thnx  tell me one more  thing how i print this values in log cat??

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440719/how-can-i-get-all-the-days-of-the-current-week-in-android
Answer 4   sample code

Comment: define an array of days of week. Then initialize calender and set the date to the calender which you required, then u can get the days according to date, U can store it into String and then u can display it into log cat.

Comment: i do not want hardcoded dates i want what ever week is current week dates

Comment: please go through given link and add the caldroid library into your project and made changes according to your requirement, I hope you will get the solution of your problem and also study the Sample Project given in it, It will be helpful for U.

Comment: IS NOT HELP ME I JUST WANT TO PRINT  CURRENT DAAYS OF WEEK

Answer (score 0):

Try this code-

```
// Current Month Days
            int startDate = 0;

                for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
                    Log.d(currentMonthName, String.valueOf(i) + " "
                            + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + " " + yy);
                     startDate=getCurrentDayOfMonth()-(list.size() % 7);
                        System.out.println("**********"+startDate);
                       if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth()) {

                        list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-"
                                + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);

                        break;
                    } else {


                        list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-"
                                + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
                    }
                }

                //removing itmem fro list
                System.out.println("----------------------"+startDate);
                System.out.println(list.size());
                for(int k=1;k<=startDate;k++){
                    System.out.println("Item remove"+k);
                    list.remove(0);
                }
```

Comment: IS WORK THNX BUT IS JUST SHOW CURRENT Date only  not tomrrow day after tomorrow and rest of week

Comment: I am sorry dear no one going to wrote your app for you.. I just given you logic..
try to add item after current date in list how many days rest in that week.
you can remove break, also and then try to remove extra dates from your list as i have remove from the top..